# Get last 2 weeks data (full week)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to run a script that pulls existing data for the last 2 weeks (full weeks Sun-Sat) irrespective of when I run it.

This does not work as it's subtracting the number of days instead of the week giving incorrect data.

```
Select 
convert(varchar(255), cast(cast(Date as varchar(255)) as date), 101) as Date, ID 
From Table
where convert(varchar(255), cast(cast(date_key as varchar(255)) as date), 101)>=DATEADD(week,-3,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Let me guess, `date_key` is an integer? Why? Anyway, all of these casts are nauseating. The *worst* way to convert a date is by converting it to a string first. And the worst possible way to display a date is in an ambiguous, regional format like `m/d/y`. Anyway, can you tell us what your starting date should be if you run your code right now (or anytime this week)? Is it November 15th?

Comment: Consider a name like "date_key" that implies it's related to a calendar table, which'll have an *actual* date type column too. But I do have to ask, what date(s) do you have that would be 255 characters long?

Comment: I have date field as Integer 20200926 in table hence converting it to date as 09/26/2020

Comment: Please don't think about a date in either of those terms (as an integer or as some regional, ambiguous format). You should never be converting any of these things into non-date/time data types just so they look a certain way.

Comment: It's a date **column** @sfaj, tables don't have "fields". But Bertrand has hit the nail on the head here; don't store dates as an `int` or a `varchar`, any of the 6 date and time data types would be far better. If you need to store a date, with no time portion, use `date` and when you **present** the data have the presentation layer determine the format.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion let me edit my query. So I have a Historical table that gets data on weekly basis for 1 full week, trying to query to pull the last 2 weeks only data. Select 
convert(varchar(255), cast(cast(Date as varchar(255)) as date), 101) as Date, ID 
From Table
where convert(varchar(255), cast(cast(Date as varchar(255)) as date), 101)>=DATEADD(week,-2,GETDATE()).

Comment: There's no confusion (other than we still don't know *exactly* what you're trying to accomplish with `DATEADD(week,-2,GETDATE())`), we're just questioning your choices, that's all. :-) Most importantly, you should never have `date field as integer` even if a 1970s data warehousing textbook might suggest it. A date column should be a `date`. Full stop.

Comment: Table with date col was created as an int it was an ask from the vendor to plug it in an interface, My query is incorrect. I need your assistance to extract data for the past 2 weeks(full week) data from a historical table. Whenever I run  that script.

Comment: If you want help you have to pay attention to all the help, not just the parts you like.

Comment: Agreed!! I appreciate your time but your script did not work for me. It was asking for conversion and throwing error.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT
convert(varchar(255), cast(cast(date_key as varchar(255)) as date), 101)as date_Key

FROM [dbo].[Table]

where datename(week, convert(varchar(255), cast(cast(date_key as varchar(255))as date), 101)) >= datename(week, getdate())-2

Answer (score -3):

You should use the built in function DATEPART(weekday, dateValue) here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This should be a comment. At best.

Comment: I figured it out! please see below along with date conversion                                      SELECT

convert(varchar(255), cast(cast(date_key as varchar(255)) as date), 101)as date_Key      FROM [dbo].[Table]

where datename(week, convert(varchar(255), cast(cast(date_key as varchar(255))as date), 101)) >=

 datename(week, getdate())-2

Comment: @sfaj That is still a very bad way to do this but I noticed that part of the confusion you've created is the query in your question (and in at least one comment) implies there is both a date_key column (integer) and a Date column (presumably not an integer). If you're showing code you're allegedly using, it should work and not reference columns that don't exist. Show the actual table structure instead of making us guess columns / types from a query that doesn't do what you want.